# When camera position set to object's, camera doesn't work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a camera with all of the default settings with the following C# script below

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Camera1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        transform.position = GameObject.Find("Thing").transform.position;

    }
}
```

The project runs normally (The player still moves), but I get this

[image: Screenshot of the project running]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the culling mask you need to create a layer for the gameObject your camera is set to follow, otherwise it will not **see through it**. You can also set its transform position just to be above/in front of it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What do you mean by in front?

Comment: Imagine there is a camera that has its objective stuck inside a wall - it will just see darkness. You can either way move it somewhere else or create a layer for player and make the camera see everything but the player

Comment: Ah nevermind, I found out that in front means less in the Z axis